# Why bikes are made lightweight?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertia

From Wikipedia:

> The most important characteristics about a racing bicycle are its
>   weight and stiffness.

If I understand correctly, the greater the weight of the body, the greater its inertia (tendency to keep moving in a straight line at constant velocity).

Why aren't bikes heavy? Then the cyclist will need to waste less energy by using the inertia of the bicycle.

Comment: What about the energy wasted to accelerate a heavy bicycle from rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lower mass means lower weight, faster acceleration, and faster speed.

You didn't understand the problem correctly. A bike moving in a straight line is kept in an unstable equilibrium. The greater the weight, the less stable the equilibrium.